# Difference between two kinds of recursive function

Tags: performance, recursion, ocaml

In OCaml, there are two ways I have seen to write a `map` function for example

```
let rec map f xs =
  match xs with
  | [] -> []
  | x::rest -> f x :: map f rest
```

and

```
let map f xs =
  let rec go xs = 
    match xs with
    | [] -> []
    | x::rest -> f x :: go rest
  in go xs
```

The second one looks like more optimizing because it is similar to loop invariant elimination but in functional programming it may involve allocating a new closure. Can anyone explain the difference between the two styles of recursive function, in particular in terms of performance? Thanks for your help!

I couldn't find similar questions in SO and I'm expecting there is a term like "recursive invariant elimination" to describe the kind of transformation from the first program to the second one.

Comment: I have never seen the second form, and I see no point in using it. If there is, this is the kind of micro-optimization that I'd expect the compiler to be able to do for me. Have you tried benchmarking them to see if there's an actual difference?

Comment: The second form is particularly useful the other way around, when the recursive function needs more arguments than you want the final function to have. For instance `let factorial n = let rec f acc n = (if n == 0 then acc else f (acc * n) (n - 1)) in f 1 n`

Comment: I've never heard of "recursive invariant elimination". It's a bit strange that you already seem to know what that is, and yet want to have it be part of the answer. Maybe you clarify that part.

Comment: @jthulhu It is weird because I just made it up. I have seen "loop invariant code motion" or "loop invariant elimination" before for compiler optimization phases. So I was wondering whether the transformation in my question is also kind of optimization and whether there is a technical term for that.

Answer (score 4):

I've always wondered the exact same thing: does the compiler optimizes invariant argument in recursive function ?
Since your question motivated me to benchmark it, let me share here my results.

### **Protocol**

I have not tried it with `map`, since it would require big lists, which would result in a stack_overflow. I could try it with `rev_map` but i don't see the point of allocating huge lists while it's easier to test an equivalent behavior on integers (plus I'm afraid that allocations. would ultimately trigger a round of GC which would mess with my time measures).

The following code reproduces your use-case with a dummy recursive function with an invariant argument, as in `map`:

```
let rec g f x = if x = 0 then 0 else g f (f x)

let g2 f x =
  let rec aux x = if x = 0 then 0 else aux (f x) in
  aux x

let time title f x =
  let t = Sys.time () in
  let fx = f x in
  Printf.printf "%s: %fs\n%!" title (Sys.time () -. t) ;
  fx

let main =
  let nb = int_of_string Sys.argv.(1) in
  ignore (time "normal" (g pred) nb) ;
  ignore (time "invariant elimination" (g2 pred) nb)
```

You can compile it (`ocamlopt a.ml` for example) and run it by doing
`./a.out 10000000000`. You can obviously change the integer parameter to tune the number of recursive calls.

### **Results**

On my computer, for an input number of 10000000000, it outputs:

```
normal: 11.813643s
invariant elimination: 11.646377s
```

On bigger values:

20000000000

```
normal: 23.353022s
invariant elimination: 22.977813s
```

30000000000

```
normal: 35.586871s
invariant elimination: 35.421313s
```

I didn't bother going higher.
This to me seems to indicate that both versions are equivalent, maybe the compiler does optimize invariant argument in recursive function and it's just not measurable, maybe it doesn't.

### **Bytecode comparison**

I have also tried to see if the generated bytecode is the same or not (ocamlc -dinstr a.ml), and it **does differ** slightly as you can see in the following code snippet

**normal**

compiling a file with only this in it:

```
let g f x =
  let rec aux f x = if x = 0 then 0 else aux f (f x) in
  aux f x
```

gives

```
    branch L2
    restart
L3: grab 1
    acc 1
    push
    const 0
    eqint
    branchifnot L4
    const 0
    return 2
L4: acc 1
    push
    acc 1
    apply 1
    push
    acc 1
    push
    offsetclosure 0
    appterm 2, 4
    restart
L1: grab 1
    closurerec 3, 0
    acc 2
    push
    acc 2
    push
    acc 2
    appterm 2, 5
L2: closure L1, 0
    push
    acc 0
    makeblock 1, 0
    pop 1
    setglobal E!
```

**invariant elimination**

compiling a file with only this in it:

```
let g2 f x =
  let rec aux x = if x = 0 then 0 else aux (f x) in
  aux x
```

gives:

```
    branch L2
L3: acc 0
    push
    const 0
    eqint
    branchifnot L4
    const 0
    return 1
L4: acc 0
    push
    envacc 1
    apply 1
    push
    offsetclosure 0
    appterm 1, 2
    restart
L1: grab 1
    acc 0
    closurerec 3, 1
    acc 2
    push
    acc 1
    appterm 1, 4
L2: closure L1, 0
    push
    acc 0
    makeblock 1, 0
    pop 1
    setglobal E2!
```

But i'm not expert enough to draw any conclusion as i don't speak bytecode.
That's also around here that i decided that the answer is not that important for now and it's easier anyway to ask @gasche next time i see him.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `go` suggests a Haskell background. Both OCaml and Haskell are functional programming languages, but there are substantial differences and what one knows about Haskell should not be used to make assumptions about OCaml.

I see no particular reason to write `map` the second way. If you're using OCaml 4.14.0 or later, you might want to use `tail_mod_cons` to make `map` tail-recursive without an explicit accumulator as in Stef's comment.

```
let[@tail_mod_cons] rec map f = 
  function 
  | [] -> [] 
  | x::xs -> f x :: map f xs
```

And of course, the real solution is:

```
let map = List.map
```

`List.map` is [implemented](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/list.ml) similarly to the above very simple implementation, but with some tweaks to ensure evaluation order and to make `tail_mod_cons` more efficient.

> ```
> let[@tail_mod_cons] rec map f = function
>     [] -> []
>   | [a1] ->
>       let r1 = f a1 in
>       [r1]
>   | a1::a2::l ->
>       let r1 = f a1 in
>       let r2 = f a2 in
>       r1::r2::map f l
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As others, I never seen the second form. And it's hard for me to imagine what kind of optimization it can provide. What I know however is that (as @Stef and @Chris pointed out) this function can be written in a tail-recursive way. So just for the sake of completeness:

```
let map f xs =
  let rec go xs ys =
    match xs with
    | [] -> ys
    | x::rest -> go rest ((f x)::ys)
  in List.rev (go xs [])
```

This version is more optimized than the two forms from your post, as each next recursive call can reuse the same stack frame eliminating unnecessary allocations, saving space and the execution time.